# Is it possible to sort a vector of string with std::sort(), based on a complex criteria?

Tags: string, sorting, std, bubble-sort

I need to sort a `std::vector<std::wstring>` which contains folder names, in a such manner that the parent folder is always located after all its children, e.g:

> C:\Main\App\QtGraphicalEffects\private
> C:\Main\App\QtGraphicalEffects
> C:\Main\App\Qt\labs\platform
> C:\Main\App\Qt\labs
> C:\Main\App\Qt
> C:\Main\App
> C:\Main\

To reach a such sorting I may use a Bubble Sort algorithm, as the following one:

```cpp
void BubbleSortDirs(std::vector<std::wstring>& dirs)
{
    bool swapped = false;

    do
    {
        swapped = false;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < dirs.size() - 1; ++i)
            // swap positions if first dir is entirely contained in the second
            if (dirs[i] != dirs[i + 1] && dirs[i + 1].find(dirs[i]) == 0)
            {
                std::swap(dirs[i], dirs[i + 1]);
                swapped = true;
            }
    }
    while (swapped);
}
```

This code works well, but I feel that a better solution should exist. So I tried to use the `std::sort` function in order to optimize my sorting, at least to provide a more elegant solution.

I tried the following implementation:

```cpp
bool SortDirs(const std::wstring& first, const std::wstring& second)
{
    // swap positions if first dir is entirely contained in the second
    return (first == second || first.find(second) == 0);
}

...

std::sort(dirs.begin(), dirs.end(), SortDirs);
```

I expected that `std::sort()` would provide the same result as the `BubbleSortDirs()` function, but it wasn't the case and the result failed in several locations. At this point I strongly suspect that `std::sort()` isn't adapted for a complex sorting criteria like the one I'm trying to apply.

So my questions are:

- What is the reason why my call to `std::sort` doesn't provide the expected result?
- Is there a way to achieve the above described sorting using the `std::sort()` function?
- If yes, what am I doing wrong?
- If no, is the above `BubbleSortDirs()` function the best way to achieve a such sorting, or does it exist something better?

Comment: did you debug why it fails, I mean it cant be hard to do

Comment: your logic works if the dirs always have \ on the end, like the last one in your example

Comment: @pm100 thank you for your answer. I disagree about the final \, indeed I see no reason why the parent folder would not be found in the children, with or without the final \. For the debug, yes I did it, however it's like the std::sort iterate through the vector only once, and either I haven't understood nothing, or the std::sort isn't adapted to my sorting criteria. And this is the purpose of my above question: determining if I misunderstood something about how std::sort is working.

Comment: well your code sorts the results correctly with trailing \ and does not sort correctly without it (as you point out) . I mean I actually ran your code, with those 7 input strings, did a random shuffle then sorted, it comes out wrong. I then debugged the function, added \ to the end of all the strings and reran the test . The strings then come out in the order you wanted. You can ignore this information if you like

Comment: @pm100 once again thank you for your answer. I don't know why the sorting is different with or without the final \ on your system, but I tested your suggestion in my code and the issue remained the same, unfortunately. Finally I could resolve it in a very simple manner: std::sort(dirs.rbegin(), dirs.rend());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my issue this way:

```cpp
std::sort(dirs.rbegin(), dirs.rend());
```